# Laravel: Accessing model attributes in the constructor method

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

How to use `__construct` on laravel eloquent and get attributes. I tired:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    dd($this->attributes);
}
```

My code return null. But on abstract class `Model` filled all attributes:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->bootIfNotBooted();

    $this->initializeTraits();

    $this->syncOriginal();

    $this->fill($attributes);
}
```

It's possible get access to model attributes in the constructor method?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible in constructor, because *attributes* list is empty.
But you can use *Events* and *boot()* method of model to achieve desired result:

```
class MyModel extends Model{

  public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    self::retrieved(function ($model) {# Called after data loaded from db
        dd($this->attributes); # now attributes was filled
    });
  }
}
```

Read more about another events here:
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-model-events-tutorialexample.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with `accessors`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Define it like:

```
public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
     return ucfirst($value);
}
```

And use `$this->first_name`something like this.

Comment: I need access to attribute in `__constructor()` method. This not work for me! @Vikash Pathak

Comment: @AndreasHunter can you please add why you need this?

Comment: I have 3 post types. Post model by default has 3 fields `title`,  `description` and `type`. I must append custom attributes to `$attributes` array checking post type on requesting. Each post type has different attributes. For detect requesting post type I must use `__construct()` method and then generate needed result with needed attributes @Vikash Pathak

Comment: @Andress why not you create a wrapper function of `find()` and do your all customer condition check there. And you can use that across all the places.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this locally by updating the constructor like this:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    dd($this->getAttributes());
}
```

However, I've discovered that when fetching the object from the database, its attributes are not filled in the constructor, and therefore it's not possible to access them there.

What you can do is access the attributes after the object has been initialized:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
dump($post->getAttributes());
```

Not sure if that helps, but it is what it is.

Maybe Events or Observers can help you with what you need: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers

Comment: Return empty `array`

Comment: I tired your updated code then again return empty `array` @GTCrais

Comment: How are you making your object?

Comment: Very simple: `$post = Post::find(1);` @GTCrais

Comment: @AndreasHunter I've tested this locally, and indeed it doesn't work. I've updated my answer once again.

Comment: How I can return different attributes by detecting post type to response before initialize object?

Comment: You should make a new StackOverflow question about that, and describe exactly what you want to achieve. I did include a couple of links in my updated answer that might help you.

Comment: I can't detect requesting post type when creating model object but tired get post type from `$_GET` and response with different attributes: `api/posts?type=book`. The inside `__construct()` added `$_GET['type']` and response result. I can't do it without  `$_GET`. @GTCrais